# Is there a way to use the Resource Governor to limit resources for some stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, sql-server-2016

We are deploying a security product that uses built in MS Sharepoint stored procedures to gather data and generate reports on our sharepoint environment. This will run on our sharepoint front end server in the same app pool as other applications.

We are worried about impact in production and looking to find a way to limit it's resources.

I set up SQL Resource Governor and created a classifier function for the application name, times and the front end server it runs on. I've been told it's too broad because the app pool has production applications that will be slowed down as well.

I went back and identified the stored procedures it runs but i'm having trouble adding them to the classifier function.

Is there a way to have the Resource Governor classifier function limit resources for selected stored procedures?

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are classified before they run any commands. You'll have to identify some difference in the connection string to trigger the classification.  Most commonly you set the ApplicationName in the connection string and retrieve it with the [APP_NAME()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/app-name-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) TSQL function.

Comment: I have that, but since this thing shares the same app pool as other applications i need a finer filter or it will limit user sessions too. Looks like this is a problem outside the normal resource governor use case.    basically this product runs under the same application name, user name and from the same server as other applications.

Comment: The IIS App Pool is irrelevant.  If two apps in the same App Pool have different ApplictionName values in their connection strings, you can classify them differently.

Comment: from the traces i've done it looks like the application names are the same and shared by varonis and other applications

Comment: Separate Apps should have separate connection strings, but you'll have to look on the IIS box, typically for ASP.NET apps, the connection string is in the web.config file for the Application.  Also it's trivial to switch an App to a new App Pool, which would give it its own process and optionally its own Windows identity.

Comment: I think I figured it out. doing some more testing, but I got resource governor working to limit a workload with millions of small procedure calls

Answer (score 0):

Took me some time but I finally figured it out. The code is a mix of the sample code from books online and my own. My problem was to create a filter for a process that runs millions of stored procedure calls in a few hours during a set time. This will filter based on time, DB and object name.

You create the table just like in the example and populate it with a return value and your times. In the time part you change the or to an and if your time block is within the same day.

```
  USE [master]
  GO

  /****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[RG_Classifier]    Script Date: 
   5/12/2020 
    11:17:45 AM ******/
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 GO

   SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
  GO


  create FUNCTION [dbo].[RG_Classifier]() RETURNS sysname 
  WITH SCHEMABINDING
    AS
  BEGIN
 DECLARE @app_name sysname
  DECLARE @strGroup sysname  
 DECLARE @loginTime time
 SET @loginTime = CONVERT(time,GETDATE()) 

  SELECT top 1   @strGroup = strGroupName  FROM dbo.tblClassificationTimeTable WHERE 
  tStartTime <= @loginTime or tEndTime >= @loginTime
   --(@loginTime between '23:00' and '23:59') or (@loginTime between '00:01' and 
'02:00')

IF 
(program_name()  in ('Application 1','Application 2'))
    and (HOST_NAME() = 'server 1')
    and (user_name() =  'login 1')
    and (db_name(29) = 'db1')
    or (db_name(10) = 'db2')
    and @strGroup is not null
     and ((OBJECT_NAME(591341171,29)) = 'proc_1')
    or ((OBJECT_NAME(1309247719,29)) = 'proc_2')
    or ((OBJECT_NAME(230291880,29)) = 'proc_3')
    or ((OBJECT_NAME(775882031,29)) = 'proc_4')
      or ((OBJECT_NAME(1474820316,10)) = 'proc_1')
    or ((OBJECT_NAME(157243615,10)) = 'proc_2')
    or ((OBJECT_NAME(1113771025,10)) = 'proc_3')
    or ((OBJECT_NAME(1155743420,10)) = 'proc_4')

    begin
    RETURN @strGroup 
    end


    SET @app_name = @strGroup 
 RETURN @app_name 
   END;
   GO
```